# Passing a value to WTForms field with Jinja2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, jinja2, wtforms

This is probably super simple.  But I'm using WTForms and want to set the value of a field to a variable I pull from the database.  But instead of displaying the dynamic variable, it's displaying the variable name.

```
{{ form.question.label }}
{{ form.question(value="{{ q.question }}") }}

{{ form.slug.label }}
{{ form.slug(value="{{ q.slug }}") }}
```

So in the field it says "{{ q.question }}" instead of something like "What is the meaning of life?".

Is there a way to display nested variables in Jinja?  Or is there some other way I need to go about this?  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think you are looking for `{{ form.slug(value = q.slug) }}`.  You have already told Jinja to parse whatever is inside the first `{{ }}`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

take out the double quotes and the template tags.

```
{{ form.question(value=q.question) }}
```

and the same for slug

Comment: Hey that's what this is for.  Don't waste time with the small stuff.  Go forth, make awesome webapps.